# Visual studio not allowing me to edit file after debug session

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am editing multiple c# files in Visual studio. I spread the files across multiple monitors so it's easier to debug. For some reason, every time I quit the debug session, 2 things will happen: A "customize" window will pop-up, and I will be unable to edit one of the files that I am working on (usually the same file every time) unless I use arrow keys to navigate to the file. I cant use the mouse to click on the file and navigate or edit it so I need to scroll on the file using only the arrow keys. This is the only way I can edit the file but it's extremely inefficient and frustrating since the file is hundreds of lines. I have tried looking up a solution online but many of them involve uninstalling and reinstalling VS which I would only like to do as a last resort. Is there another solution to this problem?

Here is the "customize" window I was referring to:

[image]

The only way I can edit my file again is if I restart VS. I can't keep restarting VS everytime I want to debug!

Additional information: when I click on the "uneditable" file, the Windows noise that plays is the same as what happens when you try to click on a window but another window requires your attention. As far as I know there are no other windows prompting me after I close the customize window.

Comment: Have you tried resetting your visual studio settings?  `Tools -> Import Export Settings -> Reset all settings`

Comment: Can you clarify what version of visual studio? [Visual Studio 2014 is not a version of visual studio](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299294/998328).

Comment: resetting all visual studio settings seems to have corrected the problem. Thank you @RobinNadeau