# Visual Studio freezing after debug session

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I asked this question before in [Visual studio not allowing me to edit file after debug session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408518/visual-studio-not-allowing-me-to-edit-file-after-debug-session) and at the time resetting the visual studio settings helped and solved the issue. This problem has returned however. Everytime after I finish debugging, VS will not allow me to edit one of the files I am working on (I am working on multiple screens). Furthermore, whenever I finish debugging, a "Customize" window will pop up.

[image]

I will try clicking on the file I want to edit after a debug session but I will not be able to click anywhere. The only way I can access the file is through the arrow keys, but this is highly inefficient since I also need to use the arrow keys to scroll. This usually happens in the same file as well. The only way to fix the issue is to restart visual studio, which is inconvenient. I have tried resetting all settings but this only worked for a short period of time. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS?

Comment: I have not, but I would like to avoid doing so since it takes a long time to reinstall as well as the fact that the person who gives administrator rights for me to download it is out of office today

Comment: Are you the only one having this issue with this (or any other) particular project in your office? If its just your machine, my recommendation is to uninstall and reinstall. And tell your admin to give you a bit more rights if you cant even download VS without them. You need to be able to do your job without an admin present!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into issues with Visual Studio where something takes the focus of from the keyboard/mouse. I have resolved it by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> multiple times until Studio comes *back*.

The other action to try is to install service update 4 for Visual Studio 2013. If it is already installed, install it again, but choose `Repair`. Reboot if necessary.